# User Defined Table Types Variable in ssis package

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, user-defined-types

I have UserDefinedTableType in my database i want to use below UserDefinedTableType as variable in ssis package. 
How can i use UserDefinedTableType as variable in ssis package.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[CMS_KeyValueTableType] AS TABLE(
    [key] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [value] [nvarchar](1000) NULL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140355.aspx

You will need to write a query to point to the table and tell ssis what values from the table will be used as the variables.